# Reading SAM files

Tags: python-3.x, security, hash, passwords, hex

I have been trying to find information on this question for a long time now and nowhere will give a straight up answer.

what I am trying to achieve is access to the hashes inside the SAM file.

I have secured a copy of the file itself and understandably it is encoded.
My problem comes about with trying to decode it into plain text so that i may read the hashes contained.

I have tried using Hex Editors but still with no success. I should add that i want as little reliance on software as is possible, but i understand this may be necessary.

So my question is as follows:

How do i access the hashes inside the SAM file in plaintext?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The files are encoded so that they cannot be read by external applications.